# how to show time on x axis using core plot ios sdk

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-plot

I need help I want to create z axis in CorePlot using scaler plot.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // We need a hostview, you can create one in IB (and create an outlet) or just do this:
    CPTGraphHostingView* hostView = [[CPTGraphHostingView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame];
    [self.view addSubview: hostView];

    // Create a CPTGraph object and add to hostView
    CPTGraph* graph = [[CPTXYGraph alloc] initWithFrame:hostView.bounds];
    hostView.hostedGraph = graph;

    // Get the (default) plotspace from the graph so we can set its x/y ranges
    CPTXYPlotSpace *plotSpace = (CPTXYPlotSpace *) graph.defaultPlotSpace;

    // Note that these CPTPlotRange are defined by START and LENGTH (not START and END) !!
    [plotSpace setYRange: [CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:CPTDecimalFromFloat( 0 ) length:CPTDecimalFromFloat( 16 )]];
    [plotSpace setXRange: [CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:CPTDecimalFromFloat( -4 ) length:CPTDecimalFromFloat( 8 )]];

    // Create the plot (we do not define actual x/y values yet, these will be supplied by the datasource...)
    CPTScatterPlot* plot = [[CPTScatterPlot alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];

    // Let's keep it simple and let this class act as datasource (therefore we implemtn <CPTPlotDataSource>)
    plot.dataSource = self;

    // Finally, add the created plot to the default plot space of the CPTGraph object we created before
    [graph addPlot:plot toPlotSpace:graph.defaultPlotSpace];
}
```

how to set x axis time like , 1:30 , 1:32, 1:35 as per as plot points.

Comment: Core Plot only supports 2D graphs. Are you trying to draw a 3D plot?

Comment: @EricSkroch : Yes i need to set 3rd axis i.e z axis in core plot.

Comment: @EricSkroch : Yes i need to set 3rd axis i.e z axis in core plot. i need right side y axis so could you pls let me know what should i do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Several of the Core Plot example apps show how to create multiple x- or y-axes. See, for example, the "Axis Demo" and the "Labeling Policy Demo" in the *Plot Gallery* app for multiple axes that share the same plot space. The "Plot Space Demo" shows how to create multiple plot spaces in a graph and assign different axes to each one.

If you want to keep the default x- and y-axes and add new ones, make a mutable copy of the `graph.axisSet.axes` array, add your new axes the array, and assign the new axis array back to the `graph.axisSet.axes` property.

Core Plot does not support 3D graphs right now, so you cannot add a true z-axis. You might be able to fake it with a scatter plot, but you'd have to do all of the 3D transform math yourself.

Comment: i want to show x axis current time as per as plotting points pls kindly help me

Comment: Have you looked at the Core Plot example apps? The *DatePlot* app and the "Date Plot" demo in the *Plot Gallery* app show several ways to format date and times on an axis.

Comment: yes i have seen but i am not able to run in simulator could you please kindly help me.

Comment: You don't have to run it to read the source code and copy it to your app (or a separate test app). See the "[Date Plot](https://github.com/core-plot/core-plot/blob/master/examples/CorePlotGallery/src/plots/DatePlot.m#L56)", for example.

Comment: thanks for reply, i have seen , but i am facing one issue regarding x axis , i want to set only time i.e current time now 15:07,15:08,15:09,15:10 and mapping as per as my array point on y axis , so now i am not able to store mintime and maxtime i.e what should be expected ? i have written code for min time & max time

Comment: pls kindly suggest me .

Comment: Edit the question to show the code you have questions about. Otherwise, we're just guessing at what the problem is.